# Does the language allow the 'set' and 'get' keywords to be used as identifiers?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have a method called `get`. The Visual Studio plug-in highlights this because it is a keyword, however, it doesn't produce a compiler error.

Is it fine to use the `set` and `get` keywords? What about other uses such as variable names or module names?

Comment: You can, as you've found. But it's just not kosher. Your 'get' method... what is it getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use them as variable or module names. The only kick in under a specific layout i.e. before a class member function:

```
class SomeClass {
    _foo;
    get foo(){
        return this._foo;
    }
    set foo(val){
        this._foo = val;
    }
}

var x = new SomeClass();
x.foo = 123; // set
console.log(x.foo); // get
```